# Open Microsoft Access Database in Blackberry Phone

Tags: java, ms-access, blackberry

Is there a way i can use an access database from my Blackberry Curve?
All i want is to be able to open the DB, open table and run queries.
How?
Thanks,

Comment: I saw a demonstration using Sharepoint, if that is any use: http://www.microsoft.com/online/mobility.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that's going to be possible due to the size of the engine needed to interface with Microsoft Access. Perhaps something like [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) would be better? If you already have data in Access, then transforming it into something like SQLite first?

Comment: ... and the fact that its Microsoft Access !!

Comment: This is just religion, not reality. Access may not be the developers choice, but it is very useful indeed for many, many people. Developers are expensive, running your own queries in Access is cheap.

Comment: You could do this with an Access file on Windows Mobile 8yrs ago. Can't imagine the hardware was any better back then or the engine being much smaller.

Comment: Pocket Access and real Access had very little to do with each other.

Comment: About as much as access and sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule you have to either adopt some web based technology, or at least get your hands on some developer tools that work on the particular product in question.

Obviously access does and run on Linux or a Mac Computer. Obviously word or excel does not run on your smartphone either.

However most smartphones do support web based technologies or have some type of web browser.

Access 2010 allows you to build web based applications. I'm currently testing and playing with some of my access applications on an apple iPad right now, and they work great.

For couple small little forms, it's probably likely cheaper and better to adopt some web based development tools like asp.net, but this is all going to come down to what type of infrastructure and web servers and other resources you have at your disposal within your organization to bring into play here.

You can take a look of the following video of mine, and you'll notice at approximately the halfway point, I switch to running the access application 100% inside of a standard based web browser.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AU4mH0jPntI

So Access 2010 + sharepoint allows you to build 100% browser neutral based applications. This means no ActiveX or even Silverlight is required.  Thus the resulting access application will run inside most modern browser, and this includes most smartphones.